# Last 6 rows for only one group

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

i have table:

```
label   added
1-1     2020-11-09 08:22:37.000
x1      2020-11-09 07:22:37.000
x3      2020-11-09 07:25:43.000
x6      2020-11-09 05:42:37.000
x1      2020-11-07 04:22:37.000
1-1     2020-11-09 08:22:37.000
1-1     2020-11-09 08:22:37.000
1-1     2020-11-06 08:22:37.000
1-1     2020-11-03 08:22:37.000
1-1     2020-11-02 08:22:37.000
1-1     2020-11-01 05:22:37.000
1-1     2020-10-09 01:52:37.000
```

I want to select all records, but for the label "1-1" only the last 6 newest.
This will probably work with the rank function:

```
SQL * FROM (
    SELECT label, added
           , RANK() OVER (PARTITION by label order by added desc) as lastN
    FROM table
) t
WHERE (label = '1-1' AND lastN <= 6)
```

But I would like to know if it can be done differently?  Maybe without a correlated subquery?

Comment: Actually, your current approach is pretty optimal.

Comment: Since you can't use `rank` and `where rank = ` in same query it is the optimal way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current rank query is pretty optimal, though you could also use `TOP` here with a union:

```sql
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE label <> '1-1'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 6 *
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE label = '1-1'
    ORDER BY added DESC
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current window function, in which `PARTITION BY` should also be removed ,  within the `ORDER BY` clause of the main query along with `TOP 6` in order to make the query without a subquery

```
SELECT TOP 6 *
  FROM [table]
 WHERE label = '1-1'
 ORDER BY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY added DESC)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23318c3921b4e0b15767cb841aeeb693)</kbd>

in this case `label` column within the `ORDER BY` clause is also redundant as being filtered out in the `WHERE` condition.